# Como usar Python adecuadamente para automation test usando aws device farm

Tags: android, python, aws

Tengo una aplicación móvil y quiero utilizar **aws device farm** para realizar **automation test**. Estoy trabajando en Mac, he intentado hace un test simple de mi aplicación Android: tocar un botón de `sign in`, tipear usuario y contraseña y hacer el login. He utilizado appium para obtener código Python para realizar mi test, subí mi apk y un archivo zip a aws pero el test siempre falla y no consigo hacer las capturas de pantalla tampoco. Soy nuevo usando Python y no pude encontrar un ejemplo que me ayude.

He seguido todos los pasos en http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-python.html pero sin exito en mi test.

Este es mi código:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import os.path
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

success = True
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['appium-version'] = '1.0'
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.0.1'
desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/APK/Squeeze.apk')
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.example.mkim.aut'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.example.mkim.aut.SuccessfulLogin'

wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
wd.implicitly_wait(60)

screenshot_folder = os.getenv('SCREENSHOT_PATH', '')
wd.save_screenshot(screenshot_folder + "/screenshot.png")


def is_alert_present(wd):
    try:
        wd.switch_to_alert().text
        return True
    except:
        return False

try:
    #self.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_folder + "/screenshot.png")
    wd.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 666, "y": 1519 })
    wd.save_screenshot(screenshot_folder + "/screenshot1.png")
    wd.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]").click()
    wd.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 121, "y": 726 })
    wd.find_element_by_name("(null)").send_keys("Squeeze@mailinator.com")
    wd.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 191, "y": 919 })
    wd.find_element_by_name("(null)").send_keys("Password")
    wd.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 563, "y": 1079 })
except:
    wd.quit()
    if not success:
        raise Exception("Test failed.")
```

Comment: A simple vista te podría comentar que la url del WebDriver es incorrecta!  esto nunca funcionaría : 'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub'

Comment: Es la que genera Appium, si no funciona por que url deberia reemplazarla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de Appium, tu url es incorrecta,

```
wd = webdriver.Remote('http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

la url del WebDriver debe ser `http://appium.testdroid.com/wd/hub`  :

```
wd = webdriver.Remote('http://appium.testdroid.com/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

Revisa los scripts de ejemplo, si estas teniendo problemas con `Python` puedes ver los ejemplos de `Java` ya que imagino estas más familiarizado al desarrollar en android:

https://github.com/bitbar/testdroid-samples/tree/master/appium/sample-scripts

Este es el ejemplo que sin duda te ayudaría para tomar los screenshots:

https://github.com/bitbar/testdroid-samples/blob/master/appium/sample-scripts/java/src/test/java/com/testdroid/appium/android/sample/SampleAppiumTest.java

Recuerda que debes subir un archivo.zip que contiene tu paquete de pruebas tanto para [**Appium Python**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-python.html#test-types-android-appium-python-uploa) :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-python.html#test-types-android-appium-python-upload

como para [**Appium Java**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html#test-types-android-appium-java-testng-upload):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html#test-types-android-appium-java-testng-upload

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Perdon por la respuesta tardia, cambiaron algunos requerimientos en la aplicacion y no pude continuar con los test hasta ahora. Me han servido de guia los links de la respuesta de @Elenasys pero aun sigo sin tener exito en Device Farm. Este es mi nuevo archivo .py:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from time import sleep

#screenshotDir = os.getenv('SCREENSHOT_PATH', '/tmp')
screenshotDir = os.getenv('/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/screenshots', '/tmp')
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['appium-version'] = '1.0'
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.0.1'
desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath('/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/APK/April-4-Android.apk')
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.example.mkim.aut'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.example.mkim.aut.SuccessfulLogin'
driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
# the emulator is sometimes slow and needs time to think
SLEEPY_TIME = 1

def log(msg):
    print (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ": " + msg)

class SqueezeLogin(unittest.TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        log ("Quitting")
        driver.quit()

    def test_LoginTest(self):
        log ("Test: Squeeze Login Test")
        # log (" Getting device screen size")
        # print driver.get_windows_size()
        isSelendroid = None
        if 'automationName' in driver.capabilities:
            if driver.capabilities['automationName'] == 'selendroid':
                isSelendroid = True

        log (" Taking screenshot: start-page.png")
        # driver.save_screenshot(screenshotDir + "/start-page.png")
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/screenshots/start-page.png")

        log (" Tap on the sign in link")
        driver.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 666, "y": 1519 })

        log (" Taking screenshot: login-page.png")
        #driver.save_screenshot(screenshotDir + "/login-page.png")
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/screenshots/login-page.png")

        log (" Tap on username and type squeeze@mailinator.com")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]").send_keys("squeeze@mailinator.com")

        log (" Taking screenshot: set-username.png")
        #driver.save_screenshot(screenshotDir + "/set-username.png")
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/screenshots/set-username.png")

        log ("Tap on Password and type Password")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.webkit.WebView[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]").send_keys("Password")

        log (" Taking screenshot: set-password")
        #driver.save_screenshot(screenshotDir + "/set-password.png")
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/screenshots/set-password.png")

        log ("Hidding keyboard")
        driver.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 302, "y": 405 })
        sleep(5)


        log (" Tap on Log in button")
        #driver.find_element_by_name("Log In").click()
        #driver.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 548, "y": 1093 })
        driver.execute_script("mobile: tap", {"tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 547, "y": 1093 })

        log (" Taking screenshot: verticals-page")
        #driver.save_screenshot(screenshotDir + "/verticals-page.png")
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/screenshots/verticals-page.png")

        log ("Test Success")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SqueezeLogin)
    # unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
    unittest.main()
```

Cree una carpeta AWS en este path:

/Users/developer/Documents

Luego ejecute:

```
$ virtualenv workspace
$ cd workspace 
$ source bin/activate
$ pip install pytest
```

Asi que este es mi path de virtualenv:

/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace y su estructura:

```
- workspace
 |
 |_ APK (.apk used in appium)
 |_ bin
 |_ include
 |_ lib
 |_ screenshots
 |_ selenium
 |_ tests (where my .py file are stored)
 |_ wheelhouse
```

Cuando ejecuto $ py.test --collect-only tests/ reconoce mi test y ejecutando $ python test_xxx.py mientras appium server esta corriendo y mi aplicacion se ejecuta en el emulador, funciona bien. Luego ejecuto:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ pip wheel --wheel-dir wheelhouse -r requirements.txt y me devuelve:

    Collecting Appium-Python-Client==0.22 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/Appium_Python_Client-0.22-cp27-none-any.whl
    Collecting appium-selector==1.2.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/appium_selector-1.2.7-cp27-none-any.whl
    Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py2-none-any.whl
    Collecting extras==0.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/extras-0.0.3-cp27-none-any.whl
    Collecting fixtures==1.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/fixtures-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting hotdog==1.5.21 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/hotdog-1.5.21-cp27-none-any.whl
    Collecting linecache2==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/linecache2-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting pbr==1.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/pbr-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting pyforge==1.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/pyforge-1.3.0-cp27-none-any.whl
    Collecting pyrsistent==0.11.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/pyrsistent-0.11.13-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl
    Collecting python-mimeparse==1.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/python_mimeparse-1.5.1-cp27-none-any.whl
    Collecting requests==2.9.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting sauceclient==0.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/sauceclient-0.2.1-cp27-none-any.whl
    Collecting selenium==2.53.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/selenium-2.53.1-py2-none-any.whl
    Collecting sentinels==0.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/sentinels-0.0.6-cp27-none-any.whl
    Collecting six==1.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting testtools==2.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/testtools-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting timeout-decorator==0.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/timeout_decorator-0.3.2-cp27-none-any.whl
    Collecting traceback2==1.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/traceback2-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting unittest2==1.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
    File was already downloaded /Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/wheelhouse/unittest2-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting vboxapi==1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vboxapi==1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21)) (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for vboxapi==1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))

$ zip -r test_login.zip tests/ wheelhouse/ requirements.txt
```

Luego hago login en la consola de AWS, creo un nuevo proyecto, subo mi archivo .apk, subo mi archivo .zip con mi test, selecciono los dispositivos y ejecuto el test. Pero sigo teniendo errores en el:

[Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtriw.png)

[No screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfVqF.png)

Asi que aun no soy capaz de obtener resultados positivos en AWS =(

Tampoco puedo obtener los screenshots, usando:

```
    screenshotDir = os.getenv('SCREENSHOT_PATH', '/tmp')
    driver.save_screenshot(screenshotDir + "/screenshot_name.png")
```

no me ha funcionado, asi que uso:

```
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("/Users/developer/Documents/AWS/workspace/screenshots/screenshot_name.png")
```

para cada screenshot.

Si ayuda en algo, estoy usando Meteor Framework en mi proyecto.

No se si necesito algo mas para que mi test sea exitoso en Device Farm, y como puedo conseguir que se tomen los screenshots, ademas quisiera saber como Device Farm me devuelve un log o que debo agregar a mi .py para generar el mismo al ejecutar mi test en Device Farm.